# Conditional data entry on certain text in excel

Tags: excel, function

I'm after some pointers.

I want to input text into some cells based on the contents of others.

Current formula that I'm using in cell B1 is

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("example",A1)),"no","yes")
```

So far, so simple. This works. Inputs 'yes' in B1 if 'example' is located in the cell A1, copy down.
However, there are some cells in the B column which have already been formatted with other text in, and I want to apply this formula on the entire spreadsheet without removing the existing text in column B. So far, the only thing I can think of is by putting this formula in the C column, copying down then moving the text from the C column to the B column - but this requires laborious copy and pasting that kind of negates the time saving provided by the formula.

What is the best way to achieve this? Do I need to resort to VB to scan the entire sheet, iterating through A1-A30000 and inserting the requisite text in B column?

Cheers.

**Edit:**

So, this has been pretty much sorted, with a variety of suggestions.

However, the actual formula I'm using is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("example",A1)),"","yes")
```

as I only want text to be put in columnB if the pattern is found. This has presented another problem! The double quotes signifying no replacement if the pattern ISN'T found actually inserts a 'NULL' character in there; when you try and select the blank cells on the next iteration of the operation, no cells are selected, as even though there is no visible character, Excel thinks there is. xD

This is solved by writing a macro function to remove Null characters.

Excel is infuriating sometimes. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the information and advice already given is definitely correct and gets the job done, 
byt thought I'd add one that does not require ANY changes to the existing data (eg sorting or filtering):

Put your formula as you described is cell B1. Apply any conditional formatting to that cell, as required.

Now select and copy (ctrl+C) cell B1. Select column B (click on column heading). 
Then Click `find and Select` (binoculars icon) - on `Home` ribbon tab. Choose `go to Special`.

In the popup choose `Blanks` and click ok. You will note all blank cells in colum B are selected. Don’t click anything, press `Crtl-V`.

Voilà, your formula and conditional formatting is pasted into all blank cells, leaving the rest alone.

[image]

---

**Quick keyboard sequence:**

- select B1
- Press ‘Ctrl + C’
- Ctrl + ‘Space Bar’
- Press ‘Ctrl + G’
- Press Tab twice to go to ‘Special…’ button, press Enter
- Press ‘K’ for blanks, Press Enter
- Press ‘Ctrl + V’
- (optional) press escape to remove selection from B1

Comment: Very nice! Thanks. I think this might be the most efficient. That is not to say the other answers are any less useful, as I've learned something from all of them. Props!

Comment: Just to check that I'm using the most efficient way to repeat this process - select columnB, CTRL-C, right click, paste special, values. This will then empty the cells where the formula hasn't evaluated.

Comment: -> select B1
-> Press ‘Ctrl + C’
-> Ctrl + ‘Space Bar’
-> Press ‘Ctrl + G’
-> Press Tab twice to go to ‘Special…’ button, press Enter
-> Press ‘K’ for blanks, Press Enter
-> Press ‘Ctrl + V’ ->(optional) press escape to remove selection from B1

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood:       if you want the results to show empty cell instead of an error you an always add `=IFERROR(your-formula,"")` around it, and avoid copy-paste special ?

Comment: or to stick to keyboard: select column B, CTRL-C, CTRL-Alt-V, V, enter, escape (I have a macro which does a "paste values" saved in my Personal.xlsb, with a ctrl-shift-v kayboard shortcut assigned)

Comment: It was to blank the formula out of the cells (except the ones that evaluated) ready for the next cycle of selecting the blank cells to evaluate on different text.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to deal with this. I'll explain 2 of them :

1. If sorting is an option, sort your table by column B (*ascending* / *A-Z*) to get all the empty values at the *top*. Write your formula in the **first blank cell** and extend it by *double-clicking* the bottom-right corner of that cell.
2. If you *cannot* sort, apply filters to the table and select **only** the blank cells in column B. Then write the formula in the first blank cell and extend it by *dragging it down* to the last cell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The double-click method seems to be the fastest way to get things done. I can sort it, but when I sort on 'Values' it only lets me choose A-Z or Z-A. Am I looking in the correct place?

Comment: This is very feasible even with 160,000 rows; I'd be concerned if we were in '95 or you had 5,000,000 rows and a VERY complicated formula.

Comment: Apologies - I have just edited my comment. I wasn't prepared for your speedy reply :)

Comment: Yes, you're at the right place. A-Z is ascending; shouldn't have used the technical term maybe.

Comment: Thanks Bernard - whilst the A-Z sorting doesn't seem to place the blank cells at the top for me in this sheet, this workaround seems to work: Go to bottom of data, CTRL-SHIFT-UPARROW > top of column; CTRL-G; special; blanks; fill with colour. Then sort on the colour, then suggestion 1. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Superb! Glad you could figure it out :D

Answer (score 1):

You might combine your existing B column values with those to be added conditionally in a single formula, say in ColumnC, such as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),IF(ISERROR(FIND("example",A1)),"no","yes"),B1)
```

copied down to suit. Then if ColumnB has become redundant, copy ColumnC, Paste Special, Values over the top and delete ColumnB. The result is to convert the formulae to the results thereof, that may increase processing speed but reduce the ease of handling additional rows (if any) subject to the same requirements.

Comment: You're right. Perhaps conditional formatting was incorrect. Conditional data entry maybe? I'm not sure of the proper excel term. That said, this seems to be another answer that would work, thanks! I will try both and see how I get on :)

Comment: Oops sorry didn't see this answer - I'll delete mine.

Comment: The only additional suggestion I had was, instead of doing copy->Paste Special, you could just leave the formulas and hide column B completely. Won't preserve any formatting, though.